# Angular Http.Post not sending request

Tags: angular

I have created a user service in `angular` for registering a user in my database, but for some reason the angular `http.post` method doesn't send any request, I also checked my network tab and the request is missing, here is my code :

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(body: User) {
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/register", body).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
} 

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  user = new User();

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
    ) { }

  register() {
    console.log(this.user)
    this.userService.registerUser(this.user);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: It means that request is failing. It seems that your register method is called or not. This is the first thing you have to verify.

Comment: Is your console message getting logged? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: i console.logged it and it is called, but the request isn't sent

Comment: i get this error in the console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:235)
    at http.js:207
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:207)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:270)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1612)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at innerSubscribe (innerSubscribe.js:67)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:57)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will sove your issue, but you don't have to subscribe into the service. The service is mainly used to get datas from API. So try :

```js
registerUser(body: User): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.post<User>("http://localhost:8080/api/register", body);
}
```

Then in your component :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.register();
}

register() {
  this.userService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: this does not work, also why did you call the register method in ngOnInit() ?

Comment: Because I don’t see where you trigger the register() method.

Comment: my apologies, it is called from the template when i submit the form

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the the http interceptor was sending the Authorization headers and for some reason when i skipped sending the headers it started working

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let auth = <string>localStorage.getItem('auth')
    console.log('Interceptor called: '+ auth);
        if (req.headers.get("skip"))
           return next.handle(req);

        if(auth !== undefined){
          req = req.clone({
            setHeaders:{ 
              Authorization: auth 
            }});
          }
        return next.handle(req);
```

and I updated the post method as goes:

```
return this.http.post<User>("http://localhost:8080/api/register", body, {headers: {skip: 'true'}});
```

Comment: This was the issue for me as well, I had an interceptor that was filtering out the call..